# Polymer toggle button checked and disabled styling

Tags: css, polymer

I'm using Polymer Toggle Button programmatically, so that user cannot interact with it. Checked and unchecked states are set according to some functions. All this part works perfectly, but styling.

I've tried the following:

```
paper-toggle-button[disabled]{
                --paper-toggle-button-checked-button-color: red;
                --paper-toggle-button-checked-bar-color: red;
                --paper-toggle-button-checked-ink-color: red;
                color: white;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
paper-toggle-button[checked][disabled]{
                --paper-toggle-button-checked-button-color: red;
                --paper-toggle-button-checked-bar-color: red;
                --paper-toggle-button-checked-ink-color: red;
                color: red;
            }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm stuck with styling a toggle with proper checked and unchecked states while it is disabled.

Hence, I have not found any information on styling disabled polymer toggles as well.

Could you please guide me where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the element default setting.

```
paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html

  :host([disabled]) .toggle-bar {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.12;
  }

  :host([disabled]) .toggle-button {
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

You could also set the checker state manually to replicate the disabled effect and use a class for the style.

```
    <paper-toggle-button 
      class='toggleDisabled' 
      checked 
      active='{{alwaysTrue}}'></paper-toggle-button>

  count: {
    type: NuBooleanber,
    readOnly: true,
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And, btw, when changing element default settings won't it break on updating dependencies for the project?

Comment: Yes, it's going to break. You have to monitor the version of the element.

Answer (score 1):

You should never edit files the **bower_components** folder for the very reason that your changes will be overwritten during an update.

However, it is possible to manually disable the `pointer-events` using CSS (which is what the [PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button/blob/master/paper-toggle-button.html) is doing when the disabled attribute is set) in order to get the effect that you want.

You could try:

```
    paper-toggle-button {
            /* Toggle Button acts as disabled but still retains coloring. */
            pointer-events: none;
            /* Apply whatever custom styling you want here (if you still need to). */
            --paper-toggle-button-checked-button-color: red;
            --paper-toggle-button-checked-bar-color: red;
            --paper-toggle-button-checked-ink-color: red;
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

Remember to remove the `disabled` attribute from the `<paper-toggle-button>` tag.